# Spring to mongo db connection using password

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose

I Create a mongodb service in docker-compose like this:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.2
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb-volumes:/var/micro-data/mongodb/data/db
    command: mongod
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongoadmin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongoadmin
    healthcheck:
      test: "mongo --eval 'db.stats().ok'"
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 60
```

and then try to connect from Spring app like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb:
  host: localhost
  port: 27017
  database: auth
  username: mongoadmin
  password: mongoadmin
```

For the first application booting up, it succeed to connect to the database, but when I try to insert some data, I got en error like this:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:418) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:228) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:48) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:280) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:55) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:207) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.finishHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:81) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:185) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:54) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:538) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openWithConcurrencyLimit(DefaultConnectionPool.java:914) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:855) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:173) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:162) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:581) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$3(OperationHelper.java:563) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:589) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:562) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.lambda$execute$3(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:232) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:268) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:84) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:212) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1010) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:471) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:454) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:448) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$16(MongoTemplate.java:1485) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:560) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1479) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1279) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1194) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:95) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ticketing.microservices.auth.services.UsersServiceImpl.createUser(UsersServiceImpl.java:37) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ticketing.microservices.auth.ui.controllers.UsersController.createUser(UsersController.java:45) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

If, I'm not using any password in my database, everything works perfectly, I got to connect to db and I can inserting some data.

**What did I do wrong?**

Note:

- I already try to use **spring.data.mongodb.uri: "mongod://mongoadmin:mongoadmin@localhost:27017/auth"** and removing all host, port, username and password setting
- I already use **command: [--auth]** and **command: [mongod, --auth]** inside docker-compose

Comment: try to change  `spring.data.mongodb:
  host: localhost ` into `spring.data.mongodb:
  host: mongodb `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mongo 2.x, you can specify a host/port in the configuration as above.

Starting from Mongo 3.0 Java driver, `spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not supported. In such cases, `spring.data.mongodb.uri` should be used to provide all of the configuration.

The problem with your `spring.data.mongodb.uri` is that `auth` there is not the target database but authentication database that is `admin` by default  [MongoDB Manual - Connection String URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/).

The correct configuration would look like

```
spring.data.mongodb:
  uri: mongod://mongoadmin:mongoadmin@localhost:27017
  database: auth
```